# How do you estimate the probability of failure in this case?

Tags: electrical, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

[image: Picture of current wiring]

The fan relay draws 6.0A. That is a safe current for 16 gauge wire. The safety fuse is tripped at 15A which is too much 16 gauge wire.

This [installation guide](http://www.kele.com/Catalog/22%20Thermostats_Controllers/PDFs/SuitePro%20Installation%20Instructions.pdf) shows the Installation Instructions for my thermostat.  On page 2 in the specification section shows Safety Fuse Amps at 15A. Fan Relay Amps is shown as 6.0A for 120 VAC which is what I have.

Background: My building superintendant installed three of these thermostats to control our fan coils in various rooms. So far we have had no issues. Recently, a Fan Coil tech came in to replace the motor and told me that the wires that is being used are too small in diameter and therefore dangerous. The length of these wires are about 2-3 feet. The work was done 4-5 years ago.

My Questions: a. Given that there has been no failures for so 5 years for 3 units, how would you estimate probability of failure in this case? I don't think it is possible.

b. Practically thinking, as shown in the assembled picture, all the wires are contained in a metal box. In case of failure, wouldn't flames in this case just fizzle out?

Thank you for your time and feedback.

**P.S. Just to be 100% clear, the fan coil originally did not come with a thermostat. It came with a off-or-low-or-high fan dial and a radio dial from hot to cold. I had the thermostat installed to control room temperature. The thermostat's control box was installed on the wall nearest to the unit. The factory wires that came with the thermostat were only a few inches long. So my super came up with the additional 2 feet of wiring needed to connect the thermostat box to the fan coil's original switch box. This 2 feet of wiring is the focus of my question and what is circled in yellow in my picture attached. In some pictures you will see all the wires exposed which happened when fan coil tech started changing the blower motor. There are pictures that show all the wires tucked in a metal box which is the steady state condition.**

[image: wires in question]
[image: wires thermostat came with]
[image: View behind front panel]
[image: Controls housing]
[image: Fan Coil Label]
[image: 15A Built-in fuse in thermostat]

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram or make/model# for your fan coils please?

Comment: Also, do you have the TB6575 (120/240V, with the flyleads) or the TB8575 (24VAC, without flyleads) model?

Comment: Is this 16 gauge wire part of UL-approved equipment, or did someone somehow get J random #16 speaker  wire and use it for AC mains?

Comment: "What are the odds of my 16 gauge wire eventually setting my home on fire?"   1 in 8.   Seriously, isn't any chance too high?

Comment: Are you asking the mean time before failure of any failure mode that includes overcurrent through the fan? Because that error would set your house on fire, or attempt to. What the mean time is, is based on the specific quality of your particular fan.

Comment: The odds are high enough that the NEC bans the use of 16AWG wire for carrying 120V when installed permanently in-wall.

Comment: @SteveWellens, there's always _some_ chance. Risk in _any_ structure with wires is above zero. The notion that a person can eliminate all risk is silly. I chuckle aloud when folks make statements that imply reality is otherwise. Like when tools are used in non-standard ways and people get all sweaty.

Comment: I predict this devolving into a popularity vote between those with a practical mindset and those harboring delusions of absolute safety. No one can give odds on the situation, so it becomes a matter of personal risk tolerance. OP writes of "fuses" and "tripping", which is contradictory, so practical solutions are nebulous. The question should be re-written to ask about remedies, not risk, and should include appropriate detail.

Comment: @isherwood Yes there is always some chance.  Like the chance you might burst into flames at any time.   So, to make you happy, I'll say _reasonable_ chance.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thank you for your relevant feedback. The fan coil unit based on my google search of the model sticker came up as https://www.carrier.com/commercial/en/us/products/airside/fan-coils/42v/ and wiring diagram is found in the docs section: https://www.shareddocs.com/hvac/docs/1005/Public/0E/42-5W.pdf. To clarify, the unit doesn't come with a thermostat. That is why I had it added later on.

Comment: @Y.Eman -- what wiring method was used to connect the thermostat to the fan coil in your situation? Can you post photos of how the thermostat is wired up, even?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel -- I've added a picture above. Thank you.

Comment: @Y.Eman -- is that photo of the wiring at the thermostat end or at the air-handler end? Can you get us a photo of the actual wiring diagram posted inside the air handler even?

Comment: @Y.Eman -- or for that matter, can you post a photo of the actual model sticker of your fan coil please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel please see attached photos. I've also added a clarification paragraph at the end.

Answer (score 2):

The bigger problem is there's no such thing as #16 wire that is certified for use in AC mains wiring inside houses.  Look at the NEC Chapter 3 wiring methods, which enumerates each and every allowed wiring method.  All of them call out wire or cable types **that do not exist in 16 AWG**.

So if 16 AWG is being used, someone is doing something illegal.

- Using 16 AWG *cordage* as a substitute for permanent wiring (NEC 400.8)
- Using 16 AWG speaker, automotive, etc. wire not approved for AC mains (NEC 110.2).

The only exception is wiring that is present inside appliances.  Those follow a different Code body called the **UL White Book**, authored and maintained by Underwriter's Laboratories.  Because of the very short distances inside appliances, and dependent on the wires' ability to cool inside the machine (or alternately approved use of high-temp wire where it has no chance of burning a user), it is possible to use smaller wires inside an appliance.

There's another Code out there called NESC which applies to utility company wiring outdoors (i.e. their side of the weatherhead).  They can overload wires in ways NEC does not allow, but remember, those wires are not inside a structure.  And the electric company has financial incentive to keep those wires cool, since it's on their side of the meter, so they pay for heating the great outdoors :) They also have direct real-time observation of the load level on those wires due to smart meters, which can be programmed to "phone home" if draw exceeds safe limits for the service drop.  Often when they upgrade someone's service, they will not upgrade the drop wires, betting that the customer won't actually use all the service they have, until the meter tells them otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, the only other situation where 16AWG is encountered for mains is with 16AWG TF(F)N aka Fixture Wire (Article 402)

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica -- Thank you for referencing the relevant codes in play. It is very helpful. I took a quick look but couldn't ascertain what size wire is called for this application. Is the next size up, 14AWG, what you recommend? Thank you.

Comment: @Y.Eman You misunderstand.  You don't size wire based on current flow *if everything works properly*, because you can't assume that.  **Breakers protect wires**.  15A   breaker = #14 or larger wire. 20A breaker = #12 or larger wire.  All wire in a 20A circuit must be #12 or larger, no #14 allowed anywhere (except inside UL-listed appliances).

Comment: @Y.Eman However, now that you have posted a photo, we see that is actually **18 gauge** ***thermostat wire***.  That is not for AC mains power at all.  That is for 24V thermostat relays.  Measure the voltage across the various leads, it should not exceed 24VAC.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica thank you for correcting me. The picture I posted of the spec shows a built-in fuse to be 15A. Doesn't this call for gauge-14 wire?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the brown cable jacket, the lack of 16 AWG pretty much anywhere in normal US installation use (120V/240V = 14 AWG and larger, Thermostat = 18 AWG, Ethernet, telephone and other comm wire even smaller), I don't believe this is 16 AWG wire at all.

**I believe this is actually 18 AWG thermostat wire!**

Which is even smaller, but at least makes some sense. An HVAC installer will have plenty of thermostat wire on hand, as it is standard for connecting thermostats to HVAC equipment. In a pinch it can be used for other things, *whether code legal or not*. In fact, the manual is actually a bit vague about the fan hookups, which will (indirectly) encourage "whatever"-mode installations.

That actually makes the technician's concerns make a lot more sense. This isn't just one level (14 -> 16) below the standard for 120V wiring, it is **two** levels below (14 -> 16 -> 18).

So where does **16 AWG** even come from? The manual makes a number of references to wire sizes, though I didn't see anything specifying the size for the fan relay wiring. A number of these reference 16 AWG, but also 14 - 22, 16 - 22, 18. So it seems to be "most popular size by default", but the reality of standard US thermostat wiring is **18 AWG**.

However, the plot thickens:

There have been a bunch of comments about "fuse" vs. "trip" (which implies breaker), etc. I think I see where all that is coming from:

- 120V/240V supply is generally protected by circuit breakers == "trip"
- The thermostat has a 15A fuse == "fuse". In other words, it has its own over-current protection. **But this fuse won't blow unless the thermostat actually uses that much power.** Relay-switched power doesn't actually count (except very indirectly if it overheats the relay, frying it, causing the thermostat to melt down).

However, the plot thickens some more:

The question mentions 6.0A. I see nothing that says the fans are actually drawing anywhere near that amount of power (which would in fact be close to the real-world recommended limit for 18 AWG wire, though still not code permitted except inside an appliance). *We actually have no idea how much power is used by the fan.* **6.0A is the limit that can be controlled by the relays.** In other words, if you have an 8.0A load, not only might you be overloading your wire (depending on a number of factors), you would be overloading the relay, likely shortening its lifetime (and therefore the lifetime of the thermostat) considerably.

**So what are the REAL concerns:**

As I see it, aside from an actual code violation, the safety concern would be if the fan motor were to have troubles such that it drew anywhere from 6A to 10A (overload relay), 10A to 15A (overload wire as well as seriously overload relay) or likely even 15A to 20A (assuming the fan is on a 20A circuit). If it suddenly bumped to 30A or more, presumably the actual circuit breaker would trip. It is these in-between values that could cause something to (literally) burn up.

Comment: Yeah, the plot *definitely* thickens here, because while 18AWG wire is legal to use on a Class 1 control circuit when protected by a suitable OCPD (7A current-limiting fuse), thermostat cables are *uniformly* type CL2 cables that are *not* legal for use on Class 1 or power circuits

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact thank you very much for clarifying the various nuances and translating the spec. The 3 bands you've listed are an excellent way to categorize and assign a probability. I haven't examined all the wires. So far I've not seen any signs of overheating. This leads me to believe the steady state current is at or below 6A. But I need to do better and protect myself against the 2nd band, 6-15A. For this, I've attached a picture from the spec showing the thermostat's built-in fuse current at 15A. Therefore, would you recommend a gauge-14 wire for this application? Thx.

Comment: I would recommend 14 AWG wire. But not having **anything** to do with the Thermostat's built in fuse. The thermostat's built in fuse covers the power **used BY the thermostat**. The fans controlled by the relays (and for that matter, the entire HVAC system controlled by the rest of the thermostat) have their own 120V or 240V power sources. The catch is that while the general HVAC system is controlled indirectly (thermostat low voltage wires to HVAC control board), the fan relays are literally just relays controlling a high voltage (120V or 240V) circuit. And therefore need to comply with the

Comment: protective requirements for such a circuit. Which, unless shown otherwise, normally means at least 14 AWG wire.

Answer (score 1):

### That thermostat cable has utterly no business being there

Your problem isn't limited to wire gauge; as it turns out, your entire thermostat setup was wired wrongly for the thermostat and unit you apparently have.  Your fan coil appears to use a line voltage (120V) control system, but the wiring connecting your thermostat to your fan coil is ordinary HVAC thermostat cable.  Not only does thermostat cable use 18AWG wires that are unsuitable for carrying 15 or 20A, it is what is called a *CL2* cable, intended *only* for use on what the NEC calls *Class 2* control circuits, such as those found in more normal HVAC units that use 24VAC for control power.  Your unit falls under the more stringent *Class 1* control circuit rules, which permit 18AWG and 16AWG *fixture wires* under some circumstances that don't appear to apply to you, but *require* wiring methods that are qualified for general mains wiring otherwise.

### Replacing this is going to take some doing

Not only do you (or more precisely, your superintendent) need to replace the cable with something that has some business being used for mains wiring, you'll need to route it from box to box as if it were a mains cable; this will involve adding a junction box (a 4" square metal box will work) at the location of the thermostat if one is not already present.  As to what sort of cable to use, I'd recommend a 12/7 W/G Metal Clad (Aluminum Interlocked Armor) cable; this will meet or exceed just about all Code requirements out there, given that this is both a short run and a retrofit situation.  You'll need to bring it into the junction boxes at both ends with MC connectors suitable for such a fat cable, by the way; based on the data I can find (.72" armor diameter, .83" jacket diameter), using an Arlington 5010AST at each end of the run will do the trick, although there are other connectors that'll work as well.

### And that 15A fuse is irrelevant to your problems, by the way

That 15A fuse you mention is meant to protect the thermostat itself from turning into a fireball in case something was to go wrong inside it.  (It also happens to protect the short 16AWG flyleads supplied with the thermostat, but *nothing more than that*; CSA certainly didn't test it to be installed with a Class 1 circuit run over CL2 thermostat cable!)